# Query_to_xml result is empty

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following problem and I hope you can help me:

If I run the following query on my postgresDB, I get a resultset where the id is '123'

```
SELECT * 
FROM public.table 
WHERE public.table.id = '123';
```

But I need to get the result in XML format. So I run the following query

```
SELECT query_to_xml('SELECT * from public.table WHERE public.table.id = CAST(123 as varchar)', TRUE, FALSE, '');
```

Unfortunately I get an empty table as a result. I don't understand the difference between the 2 queries.

Result:

```
 <table xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

 </table>
```

Note: The column 'id' is of type `varchar` in my case.

I'm not a native English speaker, so sorry for grammar mistakes. I'm also new to databases. So I hope it's not a stupid question.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you storing numbers as strings?

Comment: I have edited the query because I don't want to post the real table- and colomnnames to the whole world. The primarykey of the table is a order number which is stored as a varchar. I need a xml for every order in the table

Comment: if you want to make the two queries exactly the same, don't use cast, just escape the single quote in 123 with double single quotes, SELECT query_to_xml('SELECT * from public.table WHERE public.table.id = ''123''', TRUE, FALSE, '');

Comment: If already tried this, but I get an error:
[42703] ERROR: column "123" does not exist

Comment: it should be two single quotes, not double quotes, as in  '     '123'     '

Comment: Oh. Thank you. That solved the problem. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per comments the problem may arise because the data casting, to keep the query comparing without casting, the solution is to escape the quotes with two single quotes:

```
SELECT query_to_xml('SELECT * from public.table WHERE public.table.id = ''123''', TRUE, FALSE, '');
```